# PHP : imploding array and storing the result back to same variable

Tags: php

Are there any pit falls in the below code . Is it safe to use this way. I will not be using the array again

$records_msg = implode(" ",$records_msg);

Comment: Does this really work? Even if it does, I would use a second variable which would save the imploded array. After that I would assign this string back to the first variable. So the second one is only a helper-variable.

Comment: @faileN why wouldn't it?

Comment: Don't know, thought implode would work per reference or something, so that this would go terribly wrong. But if it works okay, But I'd never do it this way :) . Thanks

Comment: @faileN: PHP's documentation is quite good, and `implode()`'s page doesn't mention anything about references; also, it actually works like that. See http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: I know where to find the docs, believe me I'm using it since 8 years. But in fact I was to lazy to check this particular issue. So Znarkus already got the fast answer for me. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php is dynamically-typed. there is nothing wrong with choosing brevity at the expense of clarity. you may want the data types of your variables to stay consistent throughout a function/method/class/routine. but nothing in the language prevents you from doing otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, but using a different variable name for the array may improve readability, since it's not a message yet.

Answer (score 4):

That might be confusing to anyone reading your code. First `$records_msg` is an Array, then further down the code it is a String.

I would probably rename the Array to `$records_messages` and the String to `$records_message`.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing.
If you have array in array, you'll lose it.
Example:

```
<?php
$input = array(1,2,3,array(4,5));
echo implode(',', $input);
?>
```

returns:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\Temp\1.php on line 3
1,2,3,Array
```

Comment: @user406659: "never" is a long time. I've seen (and sometimes written) a lot of code which originaly assumed "that'll never happen".